# Intsalling two servers on an Azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

Can we install 2-3 windows servers on a single Azure virtual machine? Or, can we only install one operating system on a single virtual machine?

Comment: i guess you want to install either VM's on the VM or you want to multiboot? right? so unfortunately this is not possible. You don't have access to the Hypervisor and thus you can not install Hyper-V in a VM , second of all you can not choose a boot mechanism you multiboot is also out of the question :-)

Comment: Thank you for the response. So it means that if I want four servers then I need to buy 4 VMs because multiboot is not possible?

Comment: yes :-). can you elaborate on what you want to do?

Comment: We wanted to have four servers on Azure; hence, we were trying to understand that do we need exactly four VMs or can we multiboot. I guess we got the answer :)

Comment: are they all different servers? what are you willing to do, i can give some advice

Comment: If you want to run 4 services (as opposed to servers) then something like Websites/Webjob might be a better bet. As @techmike2kx says it's down to what you want to do

Comment: Yes, they are different. One is development sever, one test server, one staging server, and the last one production server.

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to look at Azure Websites. Azure Websites provides "slots" that can be configured as dev/test/staging/production very easily and you can run your entire environment on a single VM or multiple VM's (exactly what you were asking for). Websites also provides excellent publishing capabilities, whether directly from Visual Studio, TFS, Git or whatever.

Websites supports scheduled or auto-scaling, custom domains, SSL, scheduled backups (including the database) and if you need Worker Role (back-end processing) capabilities, WebJobs are built in and are easy to use.

Definitely worth checking out. It is extremely rare that I use VM's to host anything anymore. Azure Websites pretty nearly can handle anything.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for the explanation. We are planning to buy Azure IaaS subscription because we need to do development for some apps on a SharePoint server. In short, we have to create a SharePoint app which will involve lot of custom code. I am not sure whether four different Websites will help us in this regard. We actually want to go for four SharePoint servers: development, test, staging, and production. As I have now mentioned some details, do you still think we should go with the concept of Azure websites? Or buying four VMs for four SharePoint servers will be the only option?

Comment: Yes, actually you can use Azure Websites (sorry Azure Web Apps now) to host custom SharePoint/O365 apps. Here are a couple of articles to help you see if this is right for you. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2014/02/24/creating-a-sharepoint-2013-app-with-azure-web-sites.aspx and  http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/07/deploying-sp2013-provider-hosted.html. These articles are a bit dated. Its easier now to use Azure Web Apps with on-prem solutions without using Service Bus Relay. Hope this is helpful too.